# Angular - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'truck_type' doesn't have a default

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing an client portal application. Laravel-5.8 is the backend and Angular-7 is the frontend. I am using a POST REQUEST.

client-quote-landing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientQuoteService } from '../../../../shared/services/client-quote.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-client-quote-landing',
 templateUrl: './client-quote-landing.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./client-quote-landing.component.scss']
})
export class ClientQuoteLandingComponent implements OnInit {

quoteModel: any = {};
formattedAddress = '';
truck_types = [];

constructor(
private clientQuoteService: ClientQuoteService, private toastr: ToastrService,
private router: Router,
@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
this.truck_types = ["Flatbed 20 Ton", 
                    "Flatbed 40 Ton", 
                    "Flatbed 45 Ton", 
                    "Box-body 25 Ton", 
                    "Tautliner 40 Ton", 
                    "Tanker 33,000 Litres", 
                    "Tanker 45,000 Litres", 
                    "Tanker 60,000 Litres", 
                    "LPG Tube",
                    "CNG Skid"
                  ];
 }

ngOnInit() {
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

**client-quote-landing.component.html**

```
 <form name="quote" #quoteform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreateQuote(quoteform);" method="post" novalidate>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <label for="truck_type">Truck Type<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
   <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.truck_type" #truckType="ngModel" name="truck_type" required>
   <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a Truck Type</option>
   <option [ngValue]="truck_type" *ngFor="let truck_type of truck_types">{{truck_type}}</option>
   </select>
   <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truckType.invalid && ((truckType.dirty || truckType.touched) || quoteform.submitted)">
   <div style="color:red;" class="alert alert-danger">Truck Type is required.</div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <label for="loading_date">Loading Date<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
   <div class="input-group date">
   <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker] = "picker" placeholder = "Choose a date" name="loading_date" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.loading_date" #loading_date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   </mat-form-field>
   <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || quoteform.submitted)">
   <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="loading_date.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Loading Date is required.</div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <button style="margin:5px"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > Get A Quote</button>
  </form>
```

When I clicked on the submit button, nothing was happening, then I checked the network and I got this error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'truck_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `client_quotes` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `business_name`, `truck_required`, `quote_origin`, `quote_destination`, `commodity`, `loading_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Michael, Idowu, noblemfd@yahoo.com, 23456789022222, jolamic, Flatbed 20 Ton, Abeokuta, Ibadan, rice, 2019-09-27T23:00:00.000Z, 2019-09-18 15:31:15, 2019-09-18 15:31:15))"

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Post the PHP code that handles the post request, it seems that it's trying to insert `truck_required` instead of `truck_type` which is most likely caused in the form validation in the backend

Answer (score 1):

Its very clear from the error message. The meaning of the error is that there is a column named `truck_type` in the name `client_quotes` which is neither allowed to have a null value nor have a default value defined for it. In that situation, you are supposed to pass a value for that column, which you are not doing. You either pass its value in the query or just make the it `nullable()` or set a default value for it, in the laravel schema or in the database schema.

Comment: Rushing answer, OP is posting `truck_type` in the form, check the select element name attribute `<select [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.truck_type" #truckType="ngModel" name="truck_type" required>`

Comment: If you look at the error message, he is not using it in the query.

Comment: Exactly, but it should get there, do you think he actually wants to insert `Flatbed 20 Ton` that is in the `this.truck_types` array into a column named `truck_required`? he's most likely messing the column name in the backend validation

Comment: truck_type is different from truck_required. They are two different attributes. I don't know why truck_type is not appearing, may be because of the error?

Comment: @ayobamilaye where is `truck_required` coming from? It's not present in your form